# Laravel - how to Prefix all json responses to protect against json injection

Tags: api, angularjs, http, laravel, code-injection

I am writing an angularjs app which is consuming an api built with Laravel 4.1. I am looking to protect against json injection.

One method built into angularjs to fix this is to prefix all server json responses with the following string `")]}',\n"`.

The angularjs $http service will automatically strip this string from all json responses.

I don't want to have to attach this string manually to every json response which my api serves.

Is there a way to prefix this string whenever my controller returns a json Response object?

`return Response::json($prefix.$json, 200);`

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am also looking for a solution.. @gravy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538305/laravel-how-to-prefix-all-json-responses-to-protect-against-json-injection/24545383

Comment: At last, an answer! I will give it a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prepend/append data to the response you can use filters.

```
Route::filter('json.protect',function($route,$request,$response = null)
{
    if($response instanceof \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse) {
        $json = ")]}',\n" . $response->getContent();
        return $response->setContent($json);
    }
});
```

You can then attach the filter to the route using the `after` property.

```
Route::get('/test', array('after' =>'json.protect', function()
{
    $test = array(
        "foo" => "bar",
        "bar" => "foo",
    );

    return Response::json($test);
}));
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to attach a filter to each route that outputs json, then it is also possible to utilise the `App::after` hook.

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    if($response instanceof \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse) {
        $json = ")]}',\n" . $response->getContent();
        return $response->setContent($json);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but to help who needs this approach with Laravel 5 and AngularJS this can be done by creating a [Response Macro](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#response-macros), so in your `ResponseMacroServiceProvider` class you'd define `boot` method like:

```
public function boot()
{
    Response::macro('angular', function($value, $status = 200)
    {
        $response = Response::make($value, $status);

        $json = ")]}',\n" . $response->getContent();

        return $response->setContent($json);
    });
}
```

Then simply call the `response()` helper function within your controller:

```
return response()->angular(['item' => 'value']);
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
//in app/filters.php
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    if($request->ajax()) $response = ")]}',\n".$response;
});
```