# laravel how to prefix all json responses to protect against json injection

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

This topic has been request
[Laravel - how to Prefix all json responses to protect against json injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436837/laravel-how-to-prefix-all-json-responses-to-protect-against-json-injection)

without any reply so I try again.

I've tried with

```
Route::filter('protectionJson',function($route,$request ,$response)
{
    if($request->ajax() && ($response instanceof \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse)){
       return ")]}',\n".json_encode($response->getData());
    }
});
Route::get('user', array('as' => 'base.user.index', 'uses' => 'App\Controllers\UserController@index'))->before('hasAccess:users')->after('protectionJson');
```

and

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    if($request->ajax() && ($response instanceof \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse)){
       return ")]}',\n".json_encode($response->getData());
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work I mean I've got always the standar json format.

Comment: What part of the above code `doesn't work`? What have you tried to debug it so far?

Comment: @Jeemusu  I've got always the standard json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prepend/append data to the response you can access the response data using the response objects `getContent()` method.

```
Route::filter('json.protect',function($route,$request,$response = null)
{
    if($response instanceof \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse) {
        $json = ")]}',\n" . $response->getContent();
        return $response->setContent($json);
    }
});
```

You can then attach this to the route using the `after` property.

```
Route::get('/test', array('after' =>'json.protect', function()
{
    $test = array(
        "foo" => "bar",
        "bar" => "foo",
    );

    return Response::json($test);
}));
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to attach a filter to each route, then it is also possible to utilize the `App::after` hook

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    if($response instanceof \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse) {
        $json = ")]}',\n" . $response->getContent();
        return $response->setContent($json);
    }
});
```